# RODBC gives proper row count but yields empty query

Tags: r, rodbc

Using R-3.5.0 and RODBC v. 1.3-15 on Windows.
I am trying to query data from a remote database. I can connect fine and if I do a query to count the rows, the answer comes out correctly. But if I try to remove the count statement     `select count(*)` and actually get the data via `select *`, I yield an empty query (with some rather strange headers). Only two of the column names come out correctly and the rest are question marks and a number (as shown below). I can using sql developer to query the data no problem.

I include the simplest version of the code below but I get the same results if I try to limit to just a few rows or certain conditions, etc. Sorry I cannot create a reproducible example but as this is a remote db and I have no idea what the problem is, I'm not sure how I could even do that.

I can query other tables from different schemas within the same odbc connection, so I don't think it is that. I have tried with and without the `believeNRows` and the `rows_at_time`.

Thank you for any thoughts.

```
channel <- odbcConnect("mydb", uid="myuser", pwd="mypass", believeNRows=FALSE,rows_at_time = 1)

myquery <- paste("select count(*) from MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE")

sqlQuery(channel, myquery)
COUNT(*)
1 149712361

myquery <- paste("select * from MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE")
sqlQuery(channel, myquery)
[1] ID        FMC_IN_ID ?         ?.1       ?.2       ?.3       ?.4       ?.5       ?.6       ?.7       ?.8       ?.9       ?.10      ?.11      ?.12      ?.13      ?.14      ?.15     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps others, the problem was that the database contained an Oracle spatial field (MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY). R did not know what to do with it. I assumed it would just convert it to a character but instead it just got confused. By omitting the spatial field, the query worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

- add a simple `limit 100` to your query to see if you can get *some* data back
- add the `believeNRows` option to the `sqlQuery` call -- in my experience it is needed at that level

Comment: I've been using `where rownum<100` but to no avail (though with the correct count of 99). I just tried `believeNRows` in the sqlQuery option as well (hadn't tried that - thanks!) but that also did not work.

Comment: ODBC is the intersection of _two_ drivers: our RODBC as well as the _exporting driver_ provided by your backend. You haven't even told us what the vendor is -- I would recommend you google for tutorials tips for _that backend_ because that is where your issue comes from (and what `believeNRows` tries to help with).  ODBC is terrible, but still slighly better that copying csv files. But just barely.  If you can use a _direct_ driver I would try that.

Comment: The backend is Oracle. I googled for two days before posting but alas, copying csv files it may just be.  Also tried the `dbi` and `odbc` packages but to no avail. Appreciate your time Dirk Eddelbuettel.

Comment: What about the ROracle package?

Comment: Hadn't tried that one yet. I guess that's next. Thanks again!